# Something to be thankful for: The new Bible Applications site is on the launch pad! Welcome aboard!

Tags: discussion

I extend a heartfelt thank you to all who participated in the process of discussing the merit of a new Bible-related site on Stack Exchange, especially those who answered like Jesse Steele, Steve Taylor, Bach, CuriousDannii, GratefulDisciple, who demonstrated admirable organizational skills in helping to define and distinguish the vision from existing sites, and Polyhat, who offered encouraging input and support. I also thank those who offered support in comments like Tony and Anne.

Now is the time to see what this rocket can do. Some, like me, think it will roar into orbit, and others are a little more skeptical which is understandable and expected for any new enterprise. The outcome will depend on how the community responds. If your pastor, teacher, priest, or rabbi gives good practical biblical advice, :) encourage them to share their expertise here. Encourage your friends who may have questions aboutt the Bible to ask them at BA. If they are more scholarly, or interested in church history or doctrine, invite them to try BH or C.SE.

https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126301/bible-applications?referrer=ODcyZWRhNDIzODEwZmMzMjQ3NTdhMjk2MjBhMjkwYTgxMWFkYWJmZGQzNDk3YmJlY2JhNDEzYmNkMjM2YTkzNaxyBkesRf9ftqI0uhbdGCyWhK2OorTEwiX_FGGfNvss0

I have selected a stellar non-profit organization to sponsor the new site, Seed Ministries, which has supported many ministries in over 30 countries around the world.  They are interested in the practical application of the Bible for a potentially vast network of international experts and users. It will be invaluable to have their hands-on practical experience of applying the Bible to life in so many diverse situations help to shape and grow the site.

The brief description (250 characters) of Bible Applications is this:

> For people interested in understanding what the Bible says practically
> about how life is best lived today. Pastors, priests, rabbis,
> teachers, counselors and people with years of experience studying the
> Bible represent a large class of savvy experts.

In this first stage, we need 60 followers and 40 questions with a score of 10 or more. I have already posted 5 questions so if any of them are of interest to you, please vote them up or create questions that you feel would be applicable to the BA site as distinguished from other sites.

I believe we will have much to be thankful for in the days and weeks ahead!